# Generar objeto con CMake que necesita una librería enlazada

Tags: c++, cmake

Tengo un proyecto en C++ que compila con CMake. El problema que tengo es que ahora necesito agregar un objeto para compilarlo junto a mi target.

La generación del objeto la hago así:

```
Add_library(myobject OBJECT file.c)
```

El problema es que ese objeto necesita hacer uso de la librería dinamica lhiredis (que ya tengo declarado anteriormente, y que se encuentra en /use/local/lib), y eso es lo que no consigo hacer. No sé cómo construir ese objeto con el flag -lhiredis

He intentado hacer:

```
Set_target_properties(myobject PROPERTIES LINK_FLAG "-libhiredis") o "lhiredis"
```

También agregar a la creación del objeto la librería con:

```
Target_link_libraries(myobject lhiredis)
```

Implementacion de CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(rc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES /usr/local/lib ${CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES /usr/local/lib ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})


# Add Hiredis
find_library(/usr/local/lib NAMES libhiredis.so)
message(STATUS ${/usr/local/lib})
add_library(libhiredis STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libhiredis PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${/usr/local/lib})


# Code directory
add_subdirectory(src)

# Resources references in headers
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
        ../include/icc.h
        ../include/icc_rpc.h
        ../include/icdb.h
        src/root_controller.cpp)

# object icdb. AQUI EL PROBLEMA: COMO GENERAR icdb CON UNA LIB DINAMICA ENLAZADA 
add_library(**icdb** OBJECT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/icdb.c)
find_library(/usr/local/lib NAMES libhiredis.so)
message(STATUS ${/usr/local/lib})
add_library(lhiredis STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lhiredis PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${/usr/local/lib})
target_link_libraries( **icdb** lhiredis )

# Generate binary and link libs
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libhiredis **icdb**)
```

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Buenas! Gracias por el comentario, pero sí, ya había leído el cómo hacer preguntas. El problema es que es una consulta que no tiene código en sí. Es un tema de flags de compilación de un objeto intermedio con CMake. Quizá algo específico que no consigo ver siquiera en foros extranjeros haciendo una gran cantidad de búsquedas. Si es requisito, puedo dar un dummy code para el fichero .c, pero ¿cómo van a replicar los usuarios la compilación si la librería dinámica de la que hablo está en desarrollo? Es más sencillo usar una cualquiera que ya tengan instalada.  Voy a ver qué se me ocurre.

Comment: ok el problema esta en que tu POST esta basado en Opiniones o busca sugerencias, lo cual no es un tópico del sitio; si tu problema esta relacionado a un problema de código seria bienvenido.

Comment: Agregado CMake de ejemplo con el problema descrito en el código de CMake.

Comment: elimina eso de pedir sugerencias ... lo que buscas es una respuesta no sugerencias y si pides sugerencias tu post será cerrado o puede recibir votos negativos .

Comment: ok. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: ¿ `target_link_libraries( tu-target /usr/local/lib/libhiredis.so )` no te funciona ? La ruta exacta y completa hasta la librería que quieres enlazar (incluyendo el nombre de archivo completo).

Comment: @Trauma Gracias por contestar. Lo he conseguido solucionar teniendo en cuenta dos cosas: 1) He reinstalado todas las dependencias, porque no me parece normar que cmake no sea capaz de encontrar las librerías, sobre todo cuando en otros proyectos no he tenido problemas; 2) agregando los path absolutos en el "target_link_libraries" en lugar de utilizar "find_library". Creo que es posible que haya habido algún problema de permisos o algo raro. 

Tu comentario me ha dado la idea de poner los path absolutos en lugar de la búsqueda de las librerías ;)